# Kotlin - Generic abstract class that implements generic Interface

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface, jvm

I have this `abstract` `class` which accepts an `interface` as generic type:

```
abstract class A<T: GenericInterface> : T {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that the compiler will not allow me to do this and will through this error:

```
Only classes and interfaces may serve as supertypes
```

Is it any workaround about this case?

I want my classes to extends the `abstract class A` passing a custom interface that extends `GenericInterface` and to be able to implement that custom interface methods.

This is the prototype of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
abstract class A<T: GenericInterface> : T {
  ...
}

interface CustomInterface: GenericInterface {

  ...
}

class B: A<CustomInterface> {

  // Here I want to override CustomInterface funs

}
```

I know that I can always use this approach:

```
class B: A, CustomInterface {

  // override CustomInterface funs here

}
```

but for code pattern purposes I would like the other solution

Comment: I had exactly the same problem once and I didn't find a way to achieve this. Instead, I did something like this: `abstract class A<T: GenericInterface> { val obj: T }`.  Instead of requiring implementations to implement `T`, they were required to provide `T` as a separate object. In practice, they usually still implemented `T` and then returned `this`.

Comment: And I think this is impossible for technical reasons, due to type erasure. It is not a problem if we erase the type of a field, of a function param or its return type - we can compile it to `Any`/`Object` and cast on runtime. Still, we know all members of a generic type, we just don't know their specific types. Your case is much different, because now we don't even know, what methods class `A` really has - it depends on its type parameter. While I believe it could be possible to develop a language with support for such a feature, this is really much different case than "normal" generics.

Comment: @broot Yeah, for now this is not possible in Kotlin I think. Maybe in the future there will be a library that will generate the classes in compile time.